# custom UI in node-red (node-red-contrib-uibuilder & VueJS & import package)

Tags: vue.js, package, node-red

I use node-red to write data from sensors to the database. I also plan to use it to display data. For display I use node-red-contrib-uibuilder, which, as I understand it, uses VueJS. In the end, everything is fine, everything works. But the problem was revealed. Cannot add package from npm. For example vue-datepicker.

How can I add a package?

Here is the code that is:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- Note that adding an appcache really speeds things up after the first load
    You need to amend the appcache file to meet your needs.
    Don't forget to change the appcache file if you update ANY
    of the files in it otherwise the old versions will ALWAYS be used.
<html lang="en" manifest="./uibuilder.appcache">
-->
<html lang="en">
<!--
    This is the default, template html for uibuilder.
    It is meant to demonstrate the use of VueJS & bootstrap-vue to dynamically
    update the ui based on incoming/outgoing messages from/to the
    Node-RED server.

    You will want to alter this to suite your own needs. To do so,
    copy this file to <userDir>/uibuilder/<url>/src.
-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>Node-RED UI Builder</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Node-RED UI Builder - VueJS + bootstrap-vue version">

    <link rel="icon" href="./images/node-blue.ico">

    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#3f51b5">

    <!-- Used if adding to homescreen for Chrome on Android. Fallback for manifest.json -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="application-name" content="Node-RED UI Builder">

    <!-- Used if adding to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Node-RED UI Builder">

    <!-- Homescreen icons for Apple mobile use if required
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./images/manifest/icon-48x48.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="./images/manifest/icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="./images/manifest/icon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="./images/manifest/icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="./images/manifest/icon-192x192.png">
    -->

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../uibuilder/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../uibuilder/vendor/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" media="all">
    <!--<script type="tex/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-datetime@1.0.0-beta.11/dist/vue-datetime.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="tex/javascript" src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/amd/luxon.js"></script>-->
    <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-datetime@1.0.0-beta.11/dist/vue-datetime.min.css">-->
     <!-- <link href="../uibuilder/vendor/air-datetimepicker/dist/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->

</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
    <div id="app" v-cloak>
        <b-container id="app_container" class="container">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4 mt-2">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <span class="h3 text-primary">Данные по датчику</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <span class="label my-2 h-4">Название датчика:</span>
                         <select ref="selectSensor" class="form-control" v-on:input="sensorChange">
                            <option ref="optionForRemove" value="">Выберите датчик</option>
                            <option value="1111/Temperature/t1">Температура 1</option>
                            <option value="1111/Temperature/t2">Температура 2</option>
                            <option value="1111/Temperature/t3">Температура 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <input type='text' class="datepicker-here" data-position="right top" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <pre v-html="hLastRcvd" class="w-100 syntax-highlight"></pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-container>
    </div>

    <!-- These MUST be in the right order. Note no leading / -->
    <!-- REQUIRED: Socket.IO is loaded only once for all instances
                     Without this, you don't get a websocket connection -->
    <script src="../uibuilder/vendor/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <!-- --- Vendor Libraries - Load in the right order --- -->
    <script src="../uibuilder/vendor/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> <!-- dev version with component compiler -->
    <!-- <script src="../uibuilder/vendor/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>   prod version with component compiler -->
    <!-- <script src="../uibuilder/vendor/vue/dist/vue.runtime.min.js"></script>   prod version without component compiler -->
    <script src="../uibuilder/vendor/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

    <!-- REQUIRED: Sets up Socket listeners and the msg object -->
    <!-- <script src="./uibuilderfe.js"></script>   //dev version -->
    <script src="./uibuilderfe.min.js"></script> <!--    //prod version -->
    <!-- OPTIONAL: You probably want this. Put your custom code here -->
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../node_modules/air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.min.js"></script> -->

</body>

</html>
```

JS (esversion: 5):

```
/* jshint browser: true, esversion: 5, asi: true */
/*globals Vue, uibuilder */
// @ts-nocheck
/*
  Copyright (c) 2019 Julian Knight (Totally Information)

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
*/


'use strict'
// var datetime  = require('vue-datetime');
// import * as name from "vue-datetime"; 


/** @see https://github.com/TotallyInformation/node-red-contrib-uibuilder/wiki/Front-End-Library---available-properties-and-methods */

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        startMsg    : 'Vue has started, waiting for messages',
        feVersion   : '',
        socketConnectedState : false,
        serverTimeOffset     : '[unknown]',
        imgProps             : { width: 75, height: 75 },
        chartData             : null,

        msgRecvd    : '[Nothing]',
        msgsReceived: 0,
        msgCtrl     : '[Nothing]',
        msgsControl : 0,

        msgSent     : '[Nothing]',
        msgsSent    : 0,
        msgCtrlSent : '[Nothing]',
        msgsCtrlSent: 0,
    }, // --- End of data --- //
    computed: {
        hLastRcvd: function() {
            this.chartData = this.msgRecvd.chartData; 
            var msgRecvd = this.msgRecvd
            if (typeof msgRecvd === 'string') return 'Last Message Received = ' + msgRecvd
            else return 'Last Message Received = ' + this.syntaxHighlight(msgRecvd)
        },
        hLastSent: function() {
            var msgSent = this.msgSent
            if (typeof msgSent === 'string') return 'Last Message Sent = ' + msgSent
            else return 'Last Message Sent = ' + this.syntaxHighlight(msgSent)
        },
        hLastCtrlRcvd: function() {
            var msgCtrl = this.msgCtrl
            if (typeof msgCtrl === 'string') return 'Last Control Message Received = ' + msgCtrl
            else return 'Last Control Message Received = ' + this.syntaxHighlight(msgCtrl)
        },
        hLastCtrlSent: function() {
            var msgCtrlSent = this.msgCtrlSent
            if (typeof msgCtrlSent === 'string') return 'Last Control Message Sent = ' + msgCtrlSent
            //else return 'Last Message Sent = ' + this.callMethod('syntaxHighlight', [msgCtrlSent])
            else return 'Last Control Message Sent = ' + this.syntaxHighlight(msgCtrlSent)
        },
    }, // --- End of computed --- //
    methods: {
        sensorChange: function(){
            this.$refs.optionForRemove.outerHTML = "";
            var topic = 'getDataFromSensor';
            uibuilder.send( {
                'topic': topic,
                'payload': {
                    'sensor':this.$refs.selectSensor.value,
                }
            } )

        },
        // --- End of increment --- //

        // return formatted HTML version of JSON object
        syntaxHighlight: function(json) {
            json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4)
            json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
            json = json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
                var cls = 'number'
                if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                    if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                        cls = 'key'
                    } else {
                        cls = 'string'
                    }
                } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'boolean'
                } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'null'
                }
                return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>'
            })
            return json
        }, // --- End of syntaxHighlight --- //
    }, // --- End of methods --- //

    // Available hooks: init,mounted,updated,destroyed
    mounted: function(){
        //console.debug('[indexjs:Vue.mounted] app mounted - setting up uibuilder watchers')

        /** **REQUIRED** Start uibuilder comms with Node-RED @since v2.0.0-dev3
         * Pass the namespace and ioPath variables if hosting page is not in the instance root folder
         * The namespace is the "url" you put in uibuilder's configuration in the Editor.
         * e.g. If you get continual `uibuilderfe:ioSetup: SOCKET CONNECT ERROR` error messages.
         * e.g. uibuilder.start('uib', '/nr/uibuilder/vendor/socket.io') // change to use your paths/names
         */
        uibuilder.start()

        var vueApp = this

        // Example of retrieving data from uibuilder
        vueApp.feVersion = uibuilder.get('version')

        /** You can use the following to help trace how messages flow back and forth.
         * You can then amend this processing to suite your requirements.
         */

        //#region ---- Trace Received Messages ---- //
        // If msg changes - msg is updated when a standard msg is received from Node-RED over Socket.IO
        // newVal relates to the attribute being listened to.
        uibuilder.onChange('msg', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange] msg received from Node-RED server:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgRecvd = newVal
        })
        // As we receive new messages, we get an updated count as well
        uibuilder.onChange('msgsReceived', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange] Updated count of received msgs:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgsReceived = newVal
        })

        // If we receive a control message from Node-RED, we can get the new data here - we pass it to a Vue variable
        uibuilder.onChange('ctrlMsg', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:ctrlMsg] CONTROL msg received from Node-RED server:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgCtrl = newVal
        })
        // Updated count of control messages received
        uibuilder.onChange('msgsCtrl', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:msgsCtrl] Updated count of received CONTROL msgs:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgsControl = newVal
        })
        //#endregion ---- End of Trace Received Messages ---- //

        //#region ---- Trace Sent Messages ---- //
        // You probably only need these to help you understand the order of processing //
        // If a message is sent back to Node-RED, we can grab a copy here if we want to
        uibuilder.onChange('sentMsg', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:sentMsg] msg sent to Node-RED server:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgSent = newVal
        })
        // Updated count of sent messages
        uibuilder.onChange('msgsSent', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:msgsSent] Updated count of msgs sent:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgsSent = newVal
        })

        // If we send a control message to Node-RED, we can get a copy of it here
        uibuilder.onChange('sentCtrlMsg', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:sentCtrlMsg] Control message sent to Node-RED server:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgCtrlSent = newVal
        })
        // And we can get an updated count
        uibuilder.onChange('msgsSentCtrl', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:msgsSentCtrl] Updated count of CONTROL msgs sent:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgsCtrlSent = newVal
        })
        //#endregion ---- End of Trace Sent Messages ---- //

        // If Socket.IO connects/disconnects, we get true/false here
        uibuilder.onChange('ioConnected', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:ioConnected] Socket.IO Connection Status Changed to:', newVal)
            vueApp.socketConnectedState = newVal
        })
        // If Server Time Offset changes
        uibuilder.onChange('serverTimeOffset', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange:serverTimeOffset] Offset of time between the browser and the server has changed to:', newVal)
            vueApp.serverTimeOffset = newVal
        })

    } // --- End of mounted hook --- //

}) // --- End of app1 --- //

// EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a package is available on npm, you can also get it via the jsdelivr CDN: https://www.jsdelivr.com/.

For example for vue-datepicker, use : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-datepicker/ -> This will give you a listing of available files.

Use https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-datepicker/*filename* and add it as a script tag to the bottom of your uibuilder's index.html like this: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-datepicker"></script>`

After that, you can use it in index.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can add modules from NPM in the uibuilder node.

Click "manage front end libraries" from the uibuilder node options and it brings up a graphical interface for NPM.

They will go in your node-red node_modules folder (by default, ~/.node-red/node_modules)